# How to dismiss the PhpStorm code area lines?

Tags: phpstorm

In the PhpStorm's work area, there are lines in the code area.

[image]

How to set, then dismiss them?

Answer (score 1):

In **Settings | Editor | General | Appearance**, try disabling **Show method separators**:

[image]